# How do I return a managed string from a C++/CLI class

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I am creating a C++/CLI class to package an auto-generated .h file so its values can be accessed from C#

Sample.h contains (auto-generated, can't change it)

```
#define NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Bitfile "NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA.lvbitx"
static const char* const NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Signature = "D0751ADE3A0EC976606D63C425B35E85";
```

I created a C++/CLI class as follows

```
#include "Sample.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace Platform;
public ref class Sample
{
public:
    static System::String^ GetFilename() { return new System::String(NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Bitfile);};
    static System::String^ GetSignature() { return new System::String(NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Signature);};
}
```

When I try to use it from C#:

```
string bitfileName = Sample.GetFilename();
string signature = Sample.GetSignature();
```

I Get: "Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context"

I thought by doing the new I was creating a managed string

Comment: Corrected Class name error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I compile your code in VS 2012, I get two errors:

- The class is named `Sample`, but the C# code is referencing it as `OTRM_Ovd_FPGA`.
- `error C2750: 'System::String' : cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead`.

Once I corrected the class name and replaced `new` with `gcnew`, both the C++/CLI and C# code worked fine.

I do have one suggestion with your code:

```
return gcnew System::String(NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Bitfile);
```

The call to `gcnew System::String` is unnecessary. Since `NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Bitfile` is a #define, the substitution is made by the preprocessor. The C++/CLI compiler knows how to deal with quoted strings as a String^, so you can just do `return NiFpga_M_OTRM_OVDFPGA_Bitfile;`, same as you could do `return "foo";` in a method that returned `String^`. Calling `gcnew System::String` results in an unnecessary copy of the string to be constructed.

Comment: Sorry for the messed up class name, I was trying to simplify my real code on-the-fly and missed the class name change.

Comment: The I am getting is not with the C++ portion; but, the C# call into it. I am getting "Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context".  The gcnew call had no effect on that.

Comment: What does C# think the signature of `GetFilename` and `GetSignature` are?

Comment: It thinks it is returning sbyte*.  How do I get it to return a cli System::string rather than a C++/STL string?

Comment: It all works now.  I am still not sure what caused the sbyte* return; but, it is no longer doing that.

Answer (score 3):

try `gcnew System::String()` instead..

To create instance of managed classes we should use `gcnew`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ^ from your declaration

```
System::String^
```

Becomes

```
System::String
```

I believe that ^ means a managed pointer.